# Echo / Display php errors via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form which i validate via php. this is how i do it:(example is for one 1 field)

```
elseif (ctype_alpha($firstname) != true)
     {

        $err_alpha_firstname =  "First Name cannot contain numbers";
     }
```

If in case the user does use an alpha numeric firstname, i display the error as :

```
<p><input type="text" class="span2" maxlength = "20" name="firstname" required id="firstname" placeholder="First Name"></p>
              <?php if (isset($err_alpha_firstname)) {echo $err_alpha_firstname;}?>
```

It all works fine. however since this validation is server side via php, inorder for the errors to show up, i have to submit the form, which then reloads( since the form submits to the page itself) and then the errors are displayed. Now I want those errors which are stored in a `php variable  ex:$err_alpha_firstname` , to be displayed instantaneously via javascript or ajax (i dont know anything about either of the languages so pardon me please). Is there a simple script that would let me display those errors on the fly? I know php is server side and javascript is client side so there might be an issue.

html file:

```
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>Fantasy Football</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/jumbo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fantasy Football</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post" action="checkuser.php" name="check_form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name ="username" id="username" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
            <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Fantasy Football</h1>
        <p>Bring out the football manager in you!</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Register &raquo;
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">New User Registration</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" name="login_form">
        <span id="formerror" class="error"></span>
              <p><input type="text" class="span2" maxlength = "20" name="firstname" required id="firstname" placeholder="First Name"></p>
              <?php if (isset($err_alpha_firstname)) {echo $err_alpha_firstname;}?>
              <p><input type="text" class="span2" maxlength = "20" name="lastname" required id="lastame" placeholder="Last Name"></p>
              <?php if (isset($err_alpha_lastname)) {echo $err_alpha_lastname;}?>
              <p><input type="text" class="span2" maxlength = "20" name="username" required id="username" placeholder="Username"></p>
              <?php if (isset($err_ln_username)) {echo $err_ln_username;}?>
              <?php if (isset($err_empty_username)) {echo $err_empty_username;}?>
              <?php if (isset($err_alnum_username)) {echo $err_alnum_username;}?>
              <?php if (isset($err_unp)) {echo $err_unp;}?>
              <p class="help-block" style="font-size:12px"> Username should be between 4-20 characters long.</p>
              <p><input type="password" class="span2" name="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
              <?php if (isset($err_unp)) {echo $err_unp;}?>
              <?php if (isset($err_ln_password)) {echo $err_ln_password;}?>
              <?php if (isset($err_alnum_password)) {echo $err_alnum_password;}?>
              <p class="help-block" style="font-size:12px"> Password must be between 4-20 characters long. Must be alpha-numeric</p>
              <p><input type="password" class="span2" name="password_conf" placeholder="Re - Enter Password"></p>
              <?php if (isset($err_passwordconf)) {echo $err_passwordconf;}?>
              <p><input type="email" class="span4" name="emailid" required id="emailid" placeholder="Email ID"></p>
              <p><input type="text" class="span2" name="team_name" required id="team_name" placeholder="Team name"></p>
              <p class="help-block" style="font-size:12px"> Select your Unique team name.</p>
              <p>
                  <select class="secret_question">
                    <option>Select one of the below ....</option>
                     <option value ="0">The name of the city where you were born</option>
                     <option value ="1">The name of your first pet</option>
                     <option value ="2">What is your mother's maiden name</option>
                  </select>
                </p>
                <p><input type="text" class="span2" name="secret_answer" required id="secret_answer" placeholder="Secret Answer"></p>
                <p><input type="hidden" value="submit" /><br />
              <button type="submit" name="action" value = "submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button></p>
            </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Rules</h2>
          <p>Rules of the Game </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Meet The Developers</h2>
          <p>Everyones name get mentioned here </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Contact Us</h2>
          <p>have an issue with the game. Click here to contact us.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; B561 Project Fall 2013</p>
      </footer>
    </div> 


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <?php include('newuseradd.php');?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you use session cookies? Or set the header location to login.php?errid=222 if ctype validates to false. You can then fetch those using the $_GET global.

Comment: something like this -  `// if( $_POST['form_token'] != $_SESSION['form_token'])
 // {
  // echo = 'Invalid form submission';
 // } `

Comment: With jquery, ajax is clear and easy.

Comment: could you give me a sample code to work around / understand?

Comment: Use the JQuery Post method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ to send data to your php file. Echo the response. Then display the received data back onto the page. It's all in the docs. No refresh is required.

Comment: Attach your html for more direction

Comment: Can you approve my answer if it works for you?

Answer (score 2):

You could either use straight JavaScript or AJAX to PHP.
I'm going to show you the straight JS method.

You'd do something like this for each input.

```
 var hint = $("#fname-hint");
 var fname = $("#firstname");

fname.on("change", function(){
    if (!this.value.match(/\d+/g)) { // dosen't contain numbers
       hint.html("");
       fname.removeClass("error");
    }
    else {
       fname.addClass("error");
       hint.html("Your name can't contain numbers!");
    }
});
```

Now when the form is submitted, make sure there are no errors:

```
var form = $("#form");

form.submit(function(e) {
    var inputs = form.children("input");

    inputs.each(function(){
        var input = $(this);

        if (!input.hasClass("error")) {
            alert("Errors in form!");
            input.select();
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the jQuery $.post() function and return json from my php code:

```
function fail ($message){
    die(json_encode(array('status'=>'fail', 'message'=>$message)));
}

function success ($message){
    die(json_encode(array('status'=>'success', 'message'=>$message)));
}
```